# How to use this in selector in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins

I am writing a Jquery plugin where I need to use this as a selector. But its not working.

Here's the code of plugin:

```
$.fn.submitNow=function(onSuccess){
    var thisElement=this;
    $(document).on('submit',this,function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.get($(this).attr('action'),function(data){
            onSuccess.call(thisElement, data);
        });
    });
}
```

Here is the html snippet (nb. created dynamically):

```
<form action="demoLink" class="chosen-form">
    <input name="code" type="text">
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Here's the code:

```
$('.chosen-form').submitNow(function(data){
    alert(data);
});
```

My guess is ***this*** as a parameter  in the ***on()*** function cannot be used. How to pass ***this*** as a selector in **on()** function?

Comment: Really no reason to use event delegation since the way you initialize the plugin the element has to exist at that time

Comment: What exactly isn't working? Are errors thrown? Is ajax call being made? Have you considered some error handling? Your statement *"its not working"* is not a proper problem description

Comment: **this** is not passed through on() function. So entire **document** is selected instead of the form.

Comment: right...because `on()` only takes string for target selector but you don't need to delegate in the first place...use `$(this).submit(...`. Are you planning on using this on multiple forms?

Comment: If you do need to delegate then whole plugin needs to be changed

Comment: I do need to use delegate because form can be crated dynamically.
$(this).submit(... will not work if the form is created dynamically.

Comment: Then you can't use `$.fn` or if you do it needs to be bound to elements that will exist. `$('.chosen-form')` will only include elements that exist at that time. If none exist plugin won't do anything the way you are doing it now

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve with this plugin that a regular delegated event handler won't manage?

Answer (score 1):

I do not understand what your plugin will do, but answering your question:

From Jquery documentation, the selector parameter must be a string.

http://api.jquery.com/on/

[selector]

Type: String

A selector string to filter the descendants of the selected elements that trigger the event. If the selector is null or omitted, the event is always triggered when it reaches the selected element.

Comment: Is there any way to make string selector form **this**

Answer (score 1):

If you create the forms dynamically, you can't use `$(selector).widgetName()` to bind the handler. You should just use an ordinary function that takes the selector as an argument.

```
$.submitNow=function(selector, onSuccess){
    $(document).on('submit',selector,function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.get($(this).attr('action'),function(data){
            onSuccess.call(this, data);
        });
    });
};
```

Then you call it as:

```
$.submitNow('.chosen-form', function(data) {
    alert(data);
});
```